# Error: No repository for "" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?

Tags: sql-server, typeorm

The main idea is to connect 3 tables using typeorm. 2 of them work properly in the beginning:

```
module.exports = {
"type": "mssql",
"host": "xxx",
"port": 1433,
"username": "xxx",
"password": "xxx",
"database": "xxx",
"entities": [
    "build/models/**/*.js"
]}
```

The problem is when I try to connect the third table, that uses the others as "ManyToOne". Then I get this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Entity metadata for Result#RES_ControllerId was not found. Check if you specified a correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection options.

I solve this problem adding "__dirname" to entities.

```
module.exports = {
"type": "mssql",
"host": "xxx",
"port": 1433,
"username": "xxx",
"password": "xxx",
"database": "xxx",
"entities": [
  __dirname + "build/models/**/*.js"  <------ Here
]
}
```

Then the error changes to:

> No repository for "Tabla1" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?
>
> No repository for "Tabla2" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?

I´m stunk here and I don´t know how to continue with my program, there is no problem if you need something else. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `__dirname + "build/models/**/*.js"` to `"build/models/**/*{.js,.ts}"`

Comment: I had already tried it. I get the same error: Error: Entity metadata for Result#RES_ControllerId was not found. Check if you specified a correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection options.

Comment: When you build your app, could you see `build/models` directory?

Comment: Do you mean if I can see the folder `build/models` in the left bar? Where you choose the files you want to open. If you mean it, yes, I can.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you annotated the entity class with @Entity()

**Example**

```
@Entity() <-- IMPORTANT
export class Tax {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  taxId: number;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 48 })
  name: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 128 })
  description: string;

  @Column({ type: 'smallint' })
  rate: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the entity file was named incorrectly and prevented it from finding the entity file. The correct entity file name is xxx.entity.ts. When I name it xxx.ts, typescript won't report an error, but nestjs will report it.